# Dojo store concept

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am trying to dive into the data/store concepts of the Dojo Toolkit.

I understand, that Dojo Store is to replace Dojo Data API so I will try to use the new API.

There are two points which make me wonder if I have understood the concept behind this API:

- Dojo only provides the Memory Store and a Json-REST Store. If it is based on the IndexedDB API, why doesn't it provide an IndexedDB Store?
- I haven't found an example where stores are used for storing different data types. In SQL Databases you might have different tables, each having an ID column. How would I map this concept to Dojo stores: Should I use different stores to represent Person and Company (as an example)? Or should I have both in the same store? Are there any guidelines therefore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why doesn't Dojo provide an IndexedDB Store?

   Good question. I don't know.
2. I haven't found an example where stores are used for storing different data types. How would I map this concept to Dojo stores?

   Javascript is a dynamicaly typed language, so a priori nothing prevents you from storing multiple datatypes in an heterogeneous collection. The Dojo store API is purposely vague here to maintain flexibility - I view it more as a broad set of guidelines then as a hard API.

   If you use a Memory Store you can certainly add objects with different schemas to it but nothing is stopping anyone from making some kind of object store that is more strict and accepts only one kind of object per store, similarly to an SQL table.

   That said, I prefer to keep my stores homogenous, in order to avoid confusion (I would have separate stores for Person and Company). Do remember that the objects you store could possibly contain hierarchical data (sub-objects) so if you have a 1-N relationship you can use a single store for the parent objects to store everything.

Answer (score 2):

When using a store, I use three fields on all objects

- id - an id that is unique across all items in the store.  Generally a combination of type and oid.
- _type - a string value identifying the "type" of entity.  ie. Person, Company.  Having this value provides the ability to query the store and get all Persons or Companies.
- oid - THe object id uniquely identifies an object among all objects of the same type.  ie database id

I have found I have needed to create my own implementation (extend the MemoryStore) of the Store API.  You can read more about it here:

http://swingingcode.blogspot.com/2012/03/dojo-implementing-viewmodelstore.html

I have also talked about an engine written in Java that serializes java objects into the format that can be used by my store implementation.  You can read about that at

http://swingingcode.blogspot.com/2012/04/json-serialization-engine-part-i.html

http://swingingcode.blogspot.com/2012/04/json-serialization-engine-part-ii.html

Answer (score 0):

in the http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store.html ,just say

> dojo/store is **intended to supersede**, integrate, and improve upon the dojo/data API and dojox/storage API with a simple, easy to implement and extend API, based on HTML5/W3C’s IndexedDB object store API.

Comment: Yes indeed, but there is no dojo/store/IndexedDB as expected! May be work in progress with no announce, since IndexedDB itself is so-"drafty"? :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a persistent store backend:

The dojo/store API is just an API, mainly there to provide a "specification" that other Dojo / Dijit components should conform to, and that you can use to build your own store upon. As far as I know, there are no plans to provide something like an IndexedDB store from within dojo core. However, there is Storehouse, which does exactly that: providing an IndexedDB store and implementing the dojo/store API:

https://github.com/jensarps/storehouse

It is available under the same licenses as the Dojo toolkit, and it's copyrighted to the Dojo Foundation, so it's safe to use license-wise (I am a Dojo contributor and have a CLA on file).

Regarding one versus two stores:

Think of each dojo/store instance more of a table than a database; in this case, I'd recommend one store for each type, i.e. a "personStore" and a "companyStore" and handle relationships inside of your code (IndexedDB itself is not a relational database).